# Which user permission does a service need to start/stop other services?

Tags: c#, windows-services, permissions

I've wrote a service that should start/stop other services.
This is the code I'm using:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("servicename");
if(sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
{
    sc.Start();
}
```

This is the callstack of the exception. (Sorry, but the message is localized in german, but that's not relevant for understanding my problem)

> ```
> System.InvalidOperationException: Der Dienst SCardSvr kann nicht auf dem
> ```
>
> Computer . geöffnet werden. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
>   Zugriff verweigert
>          --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
>          bei System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServiceHandle(Int32
>   desiredAccess)
>          bei System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[]
>   args)
>          bei System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start()

Currently I'm running the service under 'Networkservice'. I guess that account does not suffice the necessary user rights.
 I'm going to create a new user that the most minimal permission required to start/stop arbitrary serivces.
What permissions does this new useraccount need?

Comment: Who voted to close this? Care to comment?I think this question is more appropriate on Stackoverflow than on Serverfault because this questions is viewed from a programmer's view and not from a administrator's.

Comment: Vote to close as belongs on Superuser.  This is not a programming question.  Your goal is to create a new user with permission to start/stop services.  Regardless of whether you are creating this user programmatically, determining what setup that user needs to have is a windows question, not a c# question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it need to be able to start and stop arbitrary services, or a specific set?

For more fine grained control you can set permissions against a specific service. See http://msmvps.com/blogs/erikr/archive/2007/09/26/set-permissions-on-a-specific-service-windows.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

Members of the 'power users' group have some ability to start and stop services. See http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_security_default_settings.mspx?mfr=true